# Run a view creation script without executing select in IntelliJ

Tags: sql, intellij-idea

I am using the IntelliJ run feature for SQL scripts and I have a view replacement (creation) script e.g.:

```
REPLACE VIEW a_view_name AS
SELECT
    ...
```

If I simply run this from the context menu of the sql file, IntelliJ would run the select query instead of replacing the view. Is there a way to run the view replacement script instead of the select?

Answer (score 0):

DataGrip provides smart options for executing. When the cursor is inside a query, the execution can be customized with several possible options. I.e. when you execute the query via Execute current statement action (Ctrl/Cmd+Enter default shortcut) you can choose what to execute:
[image]

Define the intended behaviour in settings:
[image]

If you want to execute the exact statement, just select it and invoke Ctrl/Cmd+Enter.